# Axios in lambda not waiting for response

Tags: javascript, axios

I am invoking axios post method in aws lambda. Most of the times lambda does not return any result.logs show the following results

> START RequestId: ac92d268-d212-4b80-a06c-927922fcf1d5 Version: $LATEST
>   END RequestId: ac92d268-d212-4b80-a06c-927922fcf1d5

But some times lambda return expected results. Looks like lambda is not waiting for axios to complete. below is lambda code.

```
var axios = require('axios')
exports.handler = async (event, context,callback) => {
    axios.post('https://example.com/testapi/api.asmx/GetNames', {})
    .then((res) => {    
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data,null,2))
      callback(null,'success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {     
      console.error(error)
      callback(null,'error');
    })    
 };
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your handler is `async` which means it will run asynchronously and return a `Promise`. This means that your function is being terminated before your code actually runs.

Since `axios` already works with Promises and your method already is `async`, you don't need to change too much. This will fix the problem:

```
const axios = require('axios')
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('https://example.com/testapi/api.asmx/GetNames', {})
        console.log(res)
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(res)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify(e)
        }
    }
};
```

You can understand more around [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) if you want to.

Comment: @Thales are you able to see why mine isn't working?  would really appreciate it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632467/how-to-convert-a-curl-request-into-an-axios-request/58633326#58633326

Comment: thanks for the A2A, @RedBaron. I checked that code and I would do the same. Don't really know what's going on. Can you add `console.log` statements and see exactly where it's hanging?

Comment: Exactly. I was wondering why getting Null response but the code exits before getting axios results.

Comment: i have the same issues. The code exits before getting axios results.

Comment: I experienced that sometimes Lambda doesn't send console.log to CloudWatch for a long time. Perhaps several minutes when the instance shuts down. Take note of the request id, then use LogInsights with `| filter @message adding "ac92d268-d212-4b80-a06c-927922fcf1d5"` to the default to find ALL the logs for your request. They could be spread out over even 10 minutes!

Comment: Use `statusCode: error.response.status` for getting the actual response status.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue where I make a 3rd party API call with Axios in Lambda, after spending almost a day noticed that my lambda had 6 seconds default timeout. Sometimes the response from the api was getting longer than 6 seconds and it was causing a 502 response.

Comment: -  I'm experiencing same thing in lambda function using axios and getting 502.  What did you do to solve it?

Comment: @TomSchreck I think I just increased the timeout value. You can do it from the console or if you use a framework like serverless, you can set it up in serverless.yml file.