# How to convert a CURL request into an axios request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, axios

I just successfully curled here:

```
curl -X POST https://jenkins-url/job/MyJob/job/some-job/job/master/build --user myemail:mypassword -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: mycrumb'
```

now I want to use axios inside my lambda

so I have this:

```
const axios = require('axios')
exports.handler = async (event) => {
      const url = "my-url";
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(url, {}, {
            auth: {
              username: 'user',
              password: 'passowrd'
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Jenkins-Crumb": "my-crumb"
            },
          }).then(function(response) {
            console.log('Authenticated');
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error on Authentication');
          });
        console.log(res)
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(res)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify(e)
        }
    }
};
```

but when I trigger the lambda it returns with: `failed with the error "Request completed but is not OK"`

not sure if I'm doing something wrong somewhere but seems to be everything is correctly mapped from CURL to axios

Comment: What happens if you take the `.then` and `.catch` continuations out of your `await`?  Which error handler is logging that message?  You're already awaiting the axios call, let the catch handler get the error and report what might be wrong.

Comment: @Joe still no success. I have ran the function locally and it works. I've also commented out the axios part and ran the lamba and it works fine. so something going on in the lambda that doesn't like in axios but it makes no sense :/ jenkins might be rejecting it

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

1. In your `.then(...)` handler, you are doing a console log, but you aren't *returning* anything from that function. Therefore, `res` is going to be `undefined`.
2. You're doing a `JSON.stringify` on `res`. `res` would be an *axios response*, not the response body. Stringifying the axios response is a bad idea, because it contains hefty object references and also circular references. You want `res.data` to give you the response data.
3. The error returned from Axios may also contain these heavy objects and circular references. In my experience, you can actually crash node when trying to serialize responses and errors from axios.

Here's how I'd modify your function:

```
const axios = require('axios')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const url = "my-url";
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, {}, {
      auth: {
        username: 'user',
        password: 'passowrd'
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Jenkins-Crumb": "my-crumb"
      },
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(res.data)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      // Don't do JSON.stringify(e). 
      // e.response.data will be the axios response body,
      // but e.response may be undefined if the error isn't an HTTP error
      body: e.stack
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hmm still not working :/ and nothing helpful in cloudwatch logs

Comment: also fyi, i have just taken this function out of lambda and ran locally and it behaves as expected so what is lambda doing wrong :/